# Why does Ie7 mysteriously cut off the top border of these notification paragraphs?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, notifications, border

I'm having problems in ie7 with notification's that are styled using the p tag. I've used them before and they render fine in IE7, however, in my latest theme, they cut off the top border with no change to the code which is giving me a major headache trying to figure out.

Here's the problematic page, the notifications are at the bottom of the page.

[Link](http://www.qwibbledesigns.co.uk/preview/Stunning%20Admin/)

It's annoying because I've used the exact same html and css here in this theme

[Link](http://www.qwibbledesigns.co.uk/demo/ControlAdmin/green/forms.html)

Can anyone see what the problem with the buggy version is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forcing layout seems to do the trick.  You can read more here:

http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Try adding this:

```
<style>
.notification { zoom:1; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have triggered some bug in IE7, but I'm not sure which one...

The difference between the pages is that you have specified a width for the notification elements in the page that works. If you specify a width for the elements in the other page, they work too.

Comment: I love that there's so many bugs in IE7 that you're "not sure which one..." =) +1 for that alone.